# Is CoC inconsistent with cnat_ind axiom?

Tags: type-theory, calculus-of-constructions

It is not possible to derive induction for Church-encoded datatypes on the Calculus of Constructions ([source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.4355)). Moreover, according to the accepted answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233736/is-it-possible-to-derive-induction-for-the-church-encoded-nat), it is also not possible to derive induction for Church-encoded datatypes on CoIC, despite the presence of inductive datatypes. As such, I wonder if we assume induction for Church-encoded Nat, `cnat_ind`; that is:

```
cnat_ind :
  (n : CNat) ->
  (P : CNat -> Type) ->
  (S : ∀ (n : CNat) -> P n -> P (csucc n)) ->
  (Z : P czero) ->
  P n
```

where `CNat`, `csucc` and `czero` are the usual Church-encoded Nat type and constructors, would that allow us to inhabit the empty type `∀ (P : *) -> P`?

Comment: Probably worth noting that `cnat_ind` is inhabited in the "simple" proof-irrelevant model (where `cnat` only has one inhabitant. This gives a simple proof of consistency, but is a little usatisfying, since we also would like this to hold in the presence of `czero =/= (csucc czero)` (or some large elimination axiom).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to show that it is consistent to add `cnat_ind` is to internalize parametricity, i.e., we extend the type system with enough structure so that it can prove its own parametricity, from which it then follows that the Church encoding of natural numbers does indeed give natural numbers. See for instance the PhD dissertation [Internalizing Parametricity](https://research.chalmers.se/publication/235758) by Guilhem Moulin.

Comment: Is there by chance any simplified implementation of this proposal available? I was following along until the part of hypercubes and so on. The notation from page 31 onwards is kinda cryptic...

Comment: I don't know about "implementation" but you could try the corresponding paper [A Presheaf Model of Parametric Type Theory](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/230735/local_230735.pdf).